# Where is apk key stored on computer?

Tags: android, apk, adt, eclipse-adt

Two engineers are working on an android project. To publish the apk (not on Playstore, but private publication), they each run their project and then get the resulting apk and then publish. As it turns out a user cannot simply update between the apks produced from the two different computers. If a user's current apk was published by developer Zack; to update to the latest version, which happen to come from developer Max, the user must in fact delete and reinstall.  How do I resolve this problem? I was hoping to find whatever key is used on one of the computers and pass it to the other developer. But I can't find where the keys are stored.

Naturally, I would use `Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package` to publish. But the present situation is as above. How do I fix that problem without having user's continuously deleting or -- on the other hand -- restrict publication to one machine?

Comment: Which IDE are you using?

Comment: I am using eclipse-adt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I put the Release Keystore file in the source control. Each developer pull the latest version (wish should not change) from the source control. You can set it up as readonly to secure the key if you like.
If you are using Eclipse when Signing the app, you have to specify the path to the keystore. So there you can get your own keystore path.

On the other hand. If you want to share the Debug Key, in order to play the application from both computers then the key is on your .android directory.
If on windows then is 
c:\Users[username].android\
debug.keystore
debug.keyset

If on linux/other is similar
~/.android

Comment: I have a mac osx, how do I navigate to the `.android` directory? is it `/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130219/sdk/platforms/android-17`? Also can I have two computers share same key?

Comment: I dont have a mac with Eclipse. However from the web it says it is on the same place as on linux. On your home directory ~/.android
You can go there by openning a terminal, from the top right on magnifying glass, type terminal.
do
cd ~/.android
ls -la
You should see the files there, from there copy them into the other machine.